# How to scrape Javascript template in Htmlunit?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, htmlunit

How to scrape 'handlerbars.js' javascript template in htmlunit 2.21?  I try to execute this, but this message shown:

> 'text/x-javascript-template' is not javascript.

and script does not execute.  I execute command `page.asXml()`.

Output text is nothing. Do you know dependency for execute javascript template in Htmlunit?   Please help.

Comment: Please provide more details at least your code.

Answer (score 1):

This Code

- HtmlUnit Config

  ```
  webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
  webClient.getBrowserVersion().setBrowserLanguage("ko-kr");

  ConfirmHandler okHandler = new ConfirmHandler() {
      @Override
      public boolean handleConfirm(Page page, String message) {
          logger.info("[Confirm] " + message);

          return true;
    }
  };

  AlertHandler alertHandler = new AlertHandler() {
      @Override
      public void handleAlert(Page page, String message) {
          logger.info("[Alert] " + message);
      }
  };

  webClient.setRefreshHandler(new ImmediateRefreshHandler());
  webClient.getOptions().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
  webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
  webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
  webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
  webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(script);
  webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
  webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
  webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(0);
  webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
  webClient.setConfirmHandler(okHandler);
  webClient.setAlertHandler(alertHandler);
  ```
- page move code

  ```
      page = webClient.getPage("https://promotions.expediapartnercentral.com/promotions/manageroomandrate.html?htid=" + siteIdx);
      webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000);
  ```
- page.asXml() repsonse is empty(script is not execute)